# How to synchronize between NORMAL and Quickfix window?

Tags: quickfix

`:vimgrep` can list search result in the Quickfix window.
`:cn` can jump to next matching and NORMAL window is also updated.

If switch to NORMAL window and `n`, it will jump to next matching place, but Quickfix windows is unchanged.

Can we make NORMAL and Quickfix window fully synchronized?

Comment: You can use :cn from your regular buffers, unless im wrong

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble If you run `:cn` several times and in NORMAL window you navigate to the first match, then `:cn` can't bring you to the second match. Basically we can't synchronise from NORMAL to Quickfix window.

Comment: Ah. So you want to be able to detect which match you’re closest to and make :cn take you to the next? Im not sure thats at all easy... id suggest becoming familiar with (a) the various :c— commands to navigate, (b) using the quickfix window to navigate results (press <CR> and see what happens), and/or (c) using tpope’s unimpaired plugin for a good set of mappings (both for quickfix and other things). Otherwise, if you know the number, i think you can do :5cc

Comment: That is, i think the concepts are different from yours—the quickfix error number is intentionally quite separate from your current location in a buffer